# Asp.net, C# Selecting radiobuttons and labels from a panel

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I ran into a new problem on my project;

I have a panel on my page in which I add labels, radiobuttons and 2 imagebuttons using pure programming code (because the number of labels and radiobuttons can be different).

I gave each radiobutton a special ID so I know in which content of the panel it belongs.
Now the big problem is I don't know how to get things from the panel.

Let's say the panel was filled with labels and radiobuttons (labels for questions and radiobuttons for the answering score 0-10) and I scored every question as asked, how do I for example select every radiobutton from the panel with an id that ends with '5' and get it's value ?

Name of the panel = pnlMain

my code : http://pastebin.com/gv8ycMY4

Thanks
I Hope you guys could help me out here because I'm really stuck on this.

grtz,
Nico

Comment: Have you defined your controls with `runat="server"`?

Comment: @Neil-Knight. He's adding them programatically, so that doesn't apply.

Comment: Maybe there's a property or some kind i forgot to add when i create these controls ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could itterate through the panel's controls to get each radiobuttonlist, then itterate through those controls to get the radio buttons.

```
foreach (Control RBL in pnlMain.Controls)
{
    if (RBL is RadioButtonList)
    {
        foreach (ListItem LI in (RBL as RadioButtonList).Items)
        {
            if (LI.Text.EndsWith("5") && LI.Selected)
            {
                // Do something with the radiobutton
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Nico. No trouble, be sure to mark my answer as the accepted one (click the tick next to it).

Comment: Any chance you know how to select only the radiobuttons wich are selected ?

Comment: Tried and tried the code over egain but when i try debug.writeline to count how many controls he finds, every time he gives 0 or 1. 
I'm sure the panel has got labels and radiobuttons becouse i put them into the panel before i run this code (panel is visible with controls on the screen). Maybe usefull : I use pure programming code to add these radiobuttons (Radiobuttons in Radiobuttonlists), not using aspx

Comment: You can only check one radio button at any one time can't you? So it would only find one that's checked.

Comment: I've got more than 1 Radiobuttonlist inside my panel, but each list can only select 1 radiobutton. For example; 4 Lists with each 7 radiobuttons, so I must have 4 checked radiobuttons selected out of my panel (sorry for my bad english)

Comment: Still not working.. Trying to get my code online to show you how i'm programming these controls

Comment: http://pastebin.com/gv8ycMY4

Here's my code. I know it's pretty shitty sorry for that

Comment: In your code you're only doing teller++ for each radiobuttonlist. To count all the radiobuttons in all lists place teller++ within the inner foreach loop. **Also, i've edited my code.** I was thinking that radiobuttons appear as child controls, but it looks like they're in the Items property of a radiobuttonlist.

Comment: Yes it is added as an Item to the list (cause I've got a problem adding radiobuttons as control to the list as you can see in the code. The code i would use to add these as a control are now set as comments but when i use the code it simply does not work)

Comment: I tried the modified code but teller still gives 0, I tried to put the teller inside the foreach (Control RBL in pnlMain.Controls) to see if he evens find any control but even then the teller gives 0. This means he can't find any controls inside the panel but I can litterly see them inside the panel on my screen

Comment: It might be that you should be adding the radio buttons each time the page loads, i'm not sure if they persist across postbacks. I'd suggest inserting a breakpoint at the start of the foreach loop, and checking values to see what you can find. Sorry, i can't offer anymore help.

Comment: It's true what you're saying, when i click a button or get a postback (except for the dropdownlist) the is empty egain. when i use the btnop_Click the pages reloads and the panel is empty egain.

Comment: This will probably help explain things: http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/092904-1.aspx

Comment: Ok, Thanks for your great help and the time you put into this today ! If I found the problem you'll be the first to know ;)

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer finally;

If you want to keep these dynamic controls after postback etc :

F.E. me, i used a SelectedIndexChange to fill up my panel with dynamic controls.
I made another method named laden() in wich i wrote my code to display these dynamic controls.
If you want these controls to pass postbacks etc simply place the following peace of code into the Page_Load method:

```
    if (Page.IsPostBack) {
        laden();
    }
```

Wich means, if you get a postback, it will Re-load these controls after postback.
Even if you got data inserted in a textbox or radiobuttons wich where selected, it will still be the same as before the postback, no data lost.

enjoy.